# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'unknown'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am getting an error as : how to generalise a return type?

```
    Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'unknown'.(7053)
```

ts code :

```
function ReturnFist<Type>(items:Type): Type {
    return items[0]; //error is here
}


const item1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const item2 = ['a','b','c'];
const item3 = [true, false, true, true];
const item4 = [{name:'one'}, {name:'two'}, {name:'thre'}, {name:'four'}];

const result1 = ReturnFist<number[]>(item1);
const result2 = ReturnFist<string[]>(item2);
const result3 = ReturnFist<boolean[]>(item3);
const result4 = ReturnFist<boolean[]>(item3);
```

[Live Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJQKZRAJzAMRgZygB4AVATwAdUA%20AChilQFt8AucqgSlcQ9UQDeAKESjEmdFiQNm%20ANoAGALoBuIQF8hWiAkKIZTAIyIAvIjmGANACZLAZksAWSwFZVQnWD0Hrp8wHIAQ39LfwAjEP8If3dPb0YmOz85KEwQVEtEYECAG3wMxFT0zKLUWN0ofQTHZIEwQKZUVn8EVH91TLqGpv8oAHc4ds76xuaoAAsJIcERnuA4LHb3DwrxVHwQHKhjMzQMbDxCIjAQJjDUTDklOgNDTjU4yokNrd9dyQOCYkJMGDAAcyuNwS1nuKy8T3WmygSXe%201wXyIYTgcByqECYCB9ASdjBjzWLygNThUkOxGRqPRmOu2OYuJUQA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to further constrain your generic type parameter:

```
function ReturnFirst<Type extends Array<any>>(items: Type): Type[number] {
  return items[0];
}
```

There are more elegant ways to write this though:

```
function ReturnFirst<Type>(items: Type[]): Type {
    return items[0];
}


const item1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const item2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const item3 = [true, false, true, true];
const item4 = [{name:'one'}, {name:'two'}, {name:'three'}, {name:'four'}];

const result1 = ReturnFirst(item1);
const result2 = ReturnFirst(item2);
const result3 = ReturnFirst(item3);
const result4 = ReturnFirst(item4);
```

Comment: But when I use the `any` it's throw error from my `eslinter` if I relax the rule, every one declaring the `any` as every where. do not know to handle